# Making a new instance of user control every time I want to change content of wpf window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been looking around and have found that the way to set the Content of a WPF Window is to set the Content of the window to a new instance of a UserControl, for example: `MyWindow.Content = new UserControl1();`

If I understand this correctly, it creates a new instance of the UserControl. Well what about when you want to go back to that previous UserControl, like if you have a back button on another UserControl? (Hopefully that made sense) Wouldn't that take up unnecessary space in memory? What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: Use a `NavigationWindow` and navigate `Page`s (per example, there are many other options). Also, creating new UserControls should not eat more memory, you should `Dispose` anything implementing it when it's removed and the rest will be taken care by the GC.

Comment: @Gusman: WPF doesn't have disposable UI objects.

Comment: _"What would be the proper way to do this?"_ -- you have lots of options, but IMHO the "proper way" is to use MVVM and let WPF worry about when and how to instantiate UI objects.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I didn't said "UI controls" but "anything", if the user is creating usercontrols he can have inside any object type stored which may need to be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is to save the usercontrol to memory, let's say the dictionary

```
public Dictionary<string, UserControl> dicForUserControl = new Dictionary<string, UserControl>();
```

Whenever you wnat to go back to the previous usercontrol, you can reset the MyWindow.Content again.

I have the similar issue before. The way I do is to use the tab control, every tab item is a usercontrol, then you can go back to any one of them by clicking the tab.

Comment: That’s a similar approach to what I was thinking. Just store it and then call it when you need it, but I was wondering if there was like a built in way with WPF/.Net to do this.